# Shortest path with blocking units and moving units on a grid

Tags: java, algorithm, grid, shortest-path

I'm trying to approach this problem of moving objects on a grid from start to finish. I'm well aware of A* Pathfinding algorithm, but I'm a bit clueless to how I can modify it so it will handle my problem:

I have a WxH grid. I need to move the star box to the empty box position (they are always in the same positions: 0,0 and W-1,H-1). My starting point is the empty (W-1,H-1) place, and each step I take is non-diagonal. If I move up, I need to move the box that blocks my way downwards to the empty space, and so forth until I reach the star (0,0) and then I need to start moving it the same way towards my starting point. To make things easier, the movement of the star is always to the direction of the starting point and never away from it. I need to find the shortest route to do so, aka the shortest number of steps required to move the star to the start position.

Here is a 2x2 grid to illustrate the problem:
[image: illustration]

This is obviously a shortest path problem (maybe A*), but I can't figure out the modifications needed here. I'm not looking for solutions or answers, just for a direction, because I'm a bit lost of where should I even start.

P.S. the grid might also have immovable boxes, but I can handle this once I understand the algorithm behind the problem itself

Comment: What restrictions are there? (e.g. grey cells) Why don't you use the trivial solution?

Comment: The restrictions are that it has to run under 1s (even for mid-size grids) and that there might be "blocked cells" which can't be moved. Also like I wrote, only diagonal movement is allowed (but that's actually a good thing, less options for me). What is the trivial solution?

Comment: Without blocked cells (eg. gray cells) the optimal solution is `8 * n - 11` movements. With blocked cells, yes, you need a search algorithm like A* (the PS is an important fact... not a PS :D sorry)

Comment: Yes, but even with the blocked cells, should I consider each cell as a node in my graph, or like the guy in the answer suggested, each state as a node?

Comment: Also the trivial solution you wrote suggests that width=height. What happens when they are not equal?

Comment: For WxH the complexity (for the trivial solution) is O(W+H). To solve the problem, simply: treat the blocked cell positions as data, white and star cell pisitions as the state and manhattan distance as A* function cost.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm not looking for solutions or answers, just for a direction, because I'm a bit lost of where should I even start.

Hint: instead of treating each block as a node in the graph, treat the entire state of all the blocks as a single node. Then the neighbors of each node are the states that can be reached in a single move.

Comment: Hence my graph is a graph of states, permutations of all the possible states and their children-states? from here finding the shortest path (aka the least amount of states) is easy as Dijkstra's. Right? But generating this graph of states requires me to use DFS or some other recursive algorithm to move down

Comment: @BoazKG: You don't need to generate the entire graph of all possible states prior to doing a search.  You can generate the nodes on the fly as you encounter them.

Comment: This fails on large grids, memory error. Instead, I changed my solution to use Lee Algorithm (BFS) and to actually move the star towards the door. While this works, there are some cases where it's not the optimal solution and I can't figure out why. I'm still stuck at this, here's the current status: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59230589/shortest-path-in-a-binary-maze-modified-with-a-twist